# QAbstractProxyModel: How to implement methods?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a TreeModel with a database like structure:

```
+Table1
   -"Table1_key" -"name"
   - 1           -"John"
   - 2           -"Peter"
   -...
+Table2
   -"Table2_key"  -"Table1_key"   -"value1"  -"value2"
   - 1            - 1             - 1000     - 20000 
   - 2            - 1             - 3000     - 4000
   - 3            - 2             - 1000     -2000
   -...
+...
```

So the Data comes from an .xml file and is displayed in a TreeView which works just fine.
However i want to display some of the Tables in different Views and resolve the keys in that view.
For the example model the required View could look like this:

```
 +"John"
       -"value1"  -"value2"
       - 1000     - 20000
       - 3000     - 4000
 +"Peter"
       - 1000     -2000
```

I guess using a QAbstractProxyModel would be the proper way.

So my question is: How do i implement this?
I can't find any examples and i have no idea how to map between the indexes of the source and the proxymodel in the mapToSource/mapFromSource methods.

Comment: Why not use a [QSortFilterProxyModel](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) instead?

Comment: @JarMan I don't want to sort or filter. I want to change the structure of the Model (change row, collumn, parent and siblings). Maybe you could post an example

Comment: You'd be better off using [`QIdentityProxyModel`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qidentityproxymodel.html).  It'll handle a lot of the basic functionality for you.

Comment: Different approach can be used, one of which is to use abstractProxyModel and overriding columnCount, rowCount, mapToSource and mapFromSource. but it might be overkill to directly map the fields and easier to build an intermediate table from your first model and directly override data and dataheader.